# Login sound disappeared

Tags: 11.10, sound, gnome, login

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with GNOME Shell. And I find that the music after login just disappeared. I run `gnome-session-properties` in terminal and I can see Gnome login sound selected.

Answer (score 1):

Open "System settings > Sound > Sound Effects" and check that alert volume is up.
Also try changing the alert sound in the same tab.

Hope it helps